# How to access the ancestor vertex during a breadth-first search with the Boost Graph Library?

Tags: c++, breadth-first-search, boost-graph

I'm trying to write my own version of connected components discovery using the breadth-first search algorithm included in the Boost Graph Library and I need to access the ancestor (the vertex which leads to the discovery of the current vertex)  vertex from withing the discover_vertex callback of my visitor to set the component number of the current vertex.
Any way it can be done easily ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an examine_vertex callback that records the vertex being examined (popped from the queue). This vertex will be the ancestor of whatever vertex is being discovered.

From the pseudo code in BGL's [BFS documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/graph/doc/breadth_first_search.html):

> vis.examine_vertex(u, g) is invoked
>   in each vertex as it is removed from
>   the queue.

```
BFS(G, s)
  for each vertex u in V[G]
    color[u] := WHITE 
    d[u] := infinity 
    p[u] := u 
  end for
  color[s] := GRAY 
  d[s] := 0 
  ENQUEUE(Q, s)
  while (Q != Ø) 
    u := DEQUEUE(Q)                   # `u` is recorded in examine_vertex callback 
    for each vertex v in Adj[u]
      if (color[v] = WHITE)
        color[v] := GRAY
        d[v] := d[u] + 1  
        p[v] := u  
        ENQUEUE(Q, v)                 # `v` is discovered, `u` is its ancestor.
      else
        if (color[v] = GRAY) 
          ...
        else 
          ...
    end for
    color[u] := BLACK
  end while
  return (d, p)
```